# How to use touchDown?

Tags: libgdx

How to use Screen and touchDown?

...

```
    playButton.addListener(new ClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            ((Game)Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new MyScreen());
        }
    });
```

...

```
public class MyScreen extends Stage implements Screen {

    public MyScreen() {
        super( new StretchViewport(320.0f, 240.0f, new OrthographicCamera()) );
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        super.act(delta);
        super.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        getViewport().update(width, height, true);
    }

    @Override public void hide() {}
    @Override public void pause() {}
    @Override public void resume() {}

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        Gdx.app.log("MyScreen","touchDown");
        return super.touchDown(screenX, screenY, pointer, button);
    }
}
```

result - empty

why `touchDown` does not fire ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've extended Stage and you use it's `touchDown()` method. What you should do is to implement `InputProcessor` to this class and implement it's methods (including `touchDown()`). Also, don't extend the stage that early. Build some apps with a '`Stage` object'.

Here's how your code should look like:

```
public class MyScreen implements Screen, InputProcessor {


    private Stage stage;
    public MyScreen() {

        stage = new Stage();
        // add some actors to the stage if necessery
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        super.act(delta);
        super.draw();

        stage.act(delta);
        stage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        // Your class now becomes the InputProcessor (it will receive events)
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
       getViewport().update(width, height, true);
    }




    // Now you override a method from the inputProcessor, not the stage (and now it will work).
    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        System.out.println("Hello, this is touchdown!")
        return false;
    }


    @Override public void hide() {}
    @Override public void pause() {}
    @Override public void resume() {}

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) 
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

**Additional info:**

`Stage` has it's own InputSystem (it extends `InputAdapter`) and also has these methods from `InputProcessor` (like touchdown, clicked etc) BUT! to make this work stage must `act()` because in the `act()` method it takes the inputs from the pool and process them. (you have to simply update the stage calling `act(delta);`).

Technically, what you've done would work, cause you've just created a Stage by creating a MyScreen object (your class extends Stage). You'd just have to call `act(delta);` in `render()` method :)

Comment: Thank you. It working. But the class has a method. Why it does not work? (Stage.touchDown) https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Stage.html#touchDown-int-int-int-int-

Comment: I've edited the answer :) Stage's input adapter is for Actors, not for you! :)